# Remover acento através de formula no Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Preciso remover sinais diacríticos(acentuação e cedilha) nos valores de uma coluna no Google Sheets. Sei que é possível e mais fácil resolver esse problema através de uma função do App Script, contudo essa é uma situação um tanto quanto corriqueira para mim, nem sempre tenho liberdade para instalar o script em determinadas planilhas. Por isso, gostaria de resolver esse problema através de uma formula, talvez com regex.

A resposta aceita [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640493/how-can-i-normalize-asciify-unicode-characters-in-google-sheets) questão apresenta um caminho possível, mas serve a um propósito diferente do meu. Além disso, essa questão foi respondida há dois anos.

Quais seriam possíveis gambiarras para meu problema?

Documentação: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=pt

Obs: acredito que a questão é relevante, pois as possíveis soluções dependerão de Regex.

Comment: Já tentou `=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2;"[ùúüû]";"u");"[èéêë]";"e");"[àáãâäå]";"a");"[íìîï]";"i");"[óòöôõ]";"o");"ç";"c")`? E com letras maiúsculas é somente adicioná-las também da mesma forma. Enfim, com script seria melhor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa função foi TOP!

Acrescentei apenas os maiúsculo:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(C2;"[ùúüû]";"u");"[èéêë]";"e");"[àáãâäå]";"a");"[íìîï]";"i");"[óòöôõ]";"o");"ç";"c");"[ÙÚÜÛ]";"U");"[ÈÉÊË]";"E");"[ÀÁÃÂÄÅ]";"A");"[ÍÌÎÏ]";"I");"[ÓÒÖÔÕ]";"O");"Ç";"C")
```